# Datetimepicker is not null after button click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datetimepicker

How can I set the null value  of two `datetimepickers` after clicking reset button:

```
$("#reset").click(function () {
    $(".k-datetimepicker input").val('');
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need an extra `)` to close the `click` function:

```
$("#reset").click(function() {
   $(".k-datetimepicker input").val('');  
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ZX6mF/

Comment: Clear and simple. Good answer :)

Comment: @sandeep - you need to refer to the `ID` of the element which is  
`#datetimepicker1`

Comment: This will reset the value of datetimepicker1, as shown here - http://jsfiddle.net/XHW3w/5/

Comment: ya i got the answer but problem is when i click the reset but if i filter again it's not showing error message for datetimepickers can you please check here http://jsfiddle.net/XHW3w/6/

Comment: means the problem is datetimepickers are not null after button click it's stroing previous value so how to set null value for datetimepickers after click reset button

Comment: @sandeep - I just had a quick look, it's because in your filter function `minDate` comes back as `null` and not a `boolean` value, so it does not evaluate correctly in your filter function.  This is a different question to the one you originally posted, you should mark this as the answer and post a new question to separate them.

Comment: hi Darren Davies if you got any idea for this bug can you please help me here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16165681/validation-message-is-not-working-properly-for-datetimepicker